# How to create and fill a file via kickstart?

Tags: linux, cat

Hi im currently writing a Oracle 8 Kickstart file for our company and i need to automatically create a file after installation and write in it. This is what i tried

```
cat <<\EOF >>/etc/sysctl.d/disableipv6.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 =1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 =1
EOF
%end
```

but it somehow messes up because the file created looks like this
`'disableipv6.conf'$'\r'`

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have DOS-style line endings in your file. Make sure you're using only newlines for EOF.

Comment: How would that look? sorry im relativly new to linux